# Document.getElementsByName() is returning object in IE but object node list in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute as my requirement . i successfully gained my requirement when i run the page in IE browser and that same not working in Chrome.

```
for(var gridNo=0;gridNo < 30;gridNo++){

        var fldId = arry[0]+'_'+arry[1]+'_'+arry[2]+'_'+arry[3]+'_'+gridNo;

       var doc = document.getElementsByName(fldId);
       alert(doc);
       var doc1=doc;
        if(eval(doc)== null){
          alert("Oops....!");
          break;
        }

        alert("The value of the Element By Name"+doc1);
        alert("The value of the Element By Id"+document.getElementById(fldId));

var selectedDropDown = getSelectedDropDownValue(document.getElementsByName(fldId));
          alert("The Value is:"+selectedDropDown);
         if(parseInt(selectedDropDown) == 0){
             gridEmpCount = gridEmpCount + 1;
         }else if(parseInt(selectedDropDown) == 1){
             gridSpouseCount = gridSpouseCount + 1;
         }else if(parseInt(selectedDropDown) == 2){
             gridParentCount = gridParentCount + 1;
         }
     }
```

Finally i came to know that i must use document.getElementById(),
its working good in IE browser but its not working in Chrome... PLZ help

Comment: Could you please show some of the code. Especially the `document.getElementsByName()` parts

Comment: What's the specific problem? Show us your code. What did you expect to happen? Attempt a solution. Why didn't it work?

Comment: You MUST show your code and relevant HTML.  We promise that `document.getElementsByName()` returns a nodeList in every browser so you have to show us what you're doing so we can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Eval is evil. EVIL!!!

Comment: `if(eval(doc)== null){` is part of your problem.  Remove the `eval()`.  It is not required in any way.  All you need is `if (!doc) {`.

Comment: @jfriend00—agreed *eval* is wrong here, but I can't see that it actually does anything harmfull.

Comment: From The above code i am trying to get drop down using document.getElementsByName(), here IE is returning Object but in chrome its returning Objectlist..

Comment: @Nagarjun - that is simply not true.  IE does not return a single object from `document.getElementsByName(fldId);`.  It returns an `HTMLCollection` or `nodeList` (basically the same thing) depending upon browser.  Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/p7bAm/.

Comment: From The above code i am trying to get drop down using document.getElementsByName(), here IE is returning Object but in chrome its returning Objectlist. But i want only object to return in chrome

Comment: @jfriend00 Thakq for your reply , here i need only one object from the list. What should i have to do?

Comment: @Nagarjun - I've posted an answer with suggested code.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.  It's hard to say which of these IE is treating oddly, but it would be true to form that IE treats bad code in odd ways.  The solution is to get rid of the bad code and then you will get a consistent behavior.  Here's a list of wrong things in your code:

1. `document.getElementsByName()` returns a list.  It does not return `null`.  It does not return a single object, ever.  The list might be empty of no DOM elements match the name.
2. `if(eval(doc)== null){` is just wrong code.  Even if `doc` was `null`, your code still wouldn't work.  You can replace that line with `if (!doc || !doc.length)` and you probably can use just `if (!doc.length)`.
3. If you want only the first element that matches the name and you're sure there is always at least one, then do this:  `getSelectedDropDownValue(document.getElementsByName(fldId)[0])`
4. You are using `document.getElementsByName(fldId)` in one place and `document.getElementById(fldId)` in another place.   Do you really mean to be using the same long string as both a name and an id?  Fetching it by id will return ONLY a single DOM object.  But fetching by name will always return a list of objects.
5. If you intend to support any version of IE before IE 9, then `parseInt()` should always be passed the radix as the second argument because otherwise it will guess the radix based on the contents of the string and will sometimes guess wrong, particularly if there is a leading zero in the string.

You didn't fully explain what you're trying to accomplish, but here's a cleaned up version of your code:

```
var fldBase = arry[0] + '_' + arry[1] + '_' + arry[2] + '_' + arry[3] + '_';
for (var gridNo = 0; gridNo < 30; gridNo++) {

    var fldId =  fldBase + gridNo;
    var doc = document.getElementsByName(fldId);
    if (!doc || !doc.length) {
        alert("Oops....!");
        break;
    }

    // use doc[0] to get the first item with the name
    var selectedDropDown = parseInt(getSelectedDropDownValue(doc[0]), 10);
    alert("The Value is:" + selectedDropDown);
    if (selectedDropDown == 0) {
        gridEmpCount = gridEmpCount + 1;
    } else if (selectedDropDown == 1) {
        gridSpouseCount = gridSpouseCount + 1;
    } else if (selectedDropDown == 2) {
        gridParentCount = gridParentCount + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @sshashank124 - that's why I suggested he use `if (!doc.length)`.  That break hims out if there is not at least one matching element.